one question about auto var in C wen I learn the coroutine and implement for static var
Now, I’m learn how to implement coroutine for static var, I found a part of code for it.
Original code:
int function(void) {
    static int i, state = 0;
    switch (state) {
        case 0: goto LABEL0;
        case 1: goto LABEL1;
    }
    LABEL0: 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        state = 1; 
        return i;
        LABEL1:; 
    }
}

This code let the i in different called present 0，1，2，3，4, ..., 9 but once I change the static i to an automatic variable, it's word Same as before:
int function(void) {
    static int state = 0;
    int i;
    switch (state) {
        case 0: goto LABEL0;
        case 1: goto LABEL1;
    }
    LABEL0: // 函数开始执行
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        state = 1; 
        return i;
        LABEL1:; 
    }
}

It should output 0,0,0,0 but actually it also output

I can only guess that when the program calls function again, the declared variable address will be the same as the previously declared variable address. I want to know if this situation is reliable?

Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates what you ovserve.

Note that static state = 0; was revoked in C99.

Since you always set i = 0 before each iteration, they will both behave the same.

@ChukwujiobiCanon, In the second case, when state ==1 (every call but the first) setting i = 0 is skipped.

I believe the answer is: No, it is not at all reliable. It is undefined behavior. In calls with state == 1, i is used without being assigned a value. The caller will presumably end up making other calls between calls to this one. That can be expected to break the accident of how it currently may appear to work.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@AviBerger I just spotted that now. Another reason I will not use goto.

@Yunnosch use my second code in mian()  some times and  print the result of function ,you will found the result is 0,1,2,3,4..

@ChukwujiobiCanon the code is a example for me to learn to creat coroutine code use static code , early stage use the goto ,later will use case to do this,but let me puzzled is the auto var in function performance static var.

You seem to have misunderstood the meaning of [mre]. Please use the meaning as described by the description/explanation I linked.

Here is an example running 2 similar co-routines that is showing this as broken. (These particular results are not guaranteed. The code is broken.)

The code with int i; as automatic storage invokes undefined behavior during the second time you call the function, because the initialization code of i is not executed at the point where state is set to 1. You jump past the i = 0.
Accessing an uninitialized automatic variable which does not have its address taken anywhere is undefined behavior, see (Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?
In general, goto jumping past declarations/initialization of local variables is very bad practice and often invokes undefined behavior.
Furthermore, the example with static int i also invokes undefined behavior when i==10 and you call the function. The for loop will break and there is a missing return statement at the end of the function at that point.
